# Run Windows based hosting among main Linux dedicated server

Tags: windows, linux, hosting, dedicated-server

I have a Linux dedicated server which runs a bunch of PHP applications.
I tried to migrate to Windows Server dedicated server last week, but I lack the IT knowledge in Windows and there are too many compatibility issues (no .htaccess and Helicon Ape making problems with non-English charsets, DNS errors, basic authentication errors, SSL errors and more...).

I need the Windows support for ASP.NET project I'm working on.

Can I somehow connect between a dedicated Linux based server with some small Windows based hosting, so for example example.com will point to an application on the Linux server and example.com/dotnet will point to some application on the Windows server?

In addition, please take into account that I also make use of SSL.

Comment: Yes.  You can have Apache (or nginx or whatever) proxy the request for certain locations through to your IIS server. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

Comment: Corbin, your comment is a great answer - please add it as an actual answer so it can be upvoted and possibly accepted.

Answer (score -2):

This is possible by creating a DNS entry. You just need to create a DNS entry (A Record) like abc.yourdomainname.com and point it to IP address of your windows server.

That means, now abc.yourdomainname.com will point to your windows server ip address.